# I want to be able to undo changes made in JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, keyboard-shortcuts, jtextarea

I want to be able to undo changes made in JTextArea. Any hints?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at

- [ExampleDepot: Adding Undo and Redo to a Text Component](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/javax.swing.undo/UndoText.html)
- [The Java Tutorials: Implementing Undo and Redo](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#undo)
- [JavaForums.org: Undo/Redo JTextArea](http://www.java-forums.org/javax-swing/9570-undo-redo-jtextarea.html)

For common tasks like these, I suggest you google before asking.